# Create one or more directories based on the names

Tags: python

I wonder if someone can help me with python script:

1. Ask the user the name of the new directory that will be added. 
   Add the directory name to a new list.
2. Ask the user to respond with ‘Yes’ or ‘No’ as to whether they would like to add 
   another directory.

-If the response is ‘No’ then create a directory for the name(s) in the list.

- Quit execution of the script after the directories have been completed.
- Before exiting the script inform the user that the directories have been created. 
  -If the response is ‘Yes’ then ask the user the name of the new directory to create.

-Add that name to the list created above

-If the response is anything other than the above two options (i.e. they did 
not type neither ‘Yes’ nor ‘No’) then repeat the question.

This is what I have done so far, it creates new directory but later I get stuck with ‘Yes’ response:

```
import os
root_path = r"C:\XYZ"
list_dir = []
userinput1 = raw_input("Please enter the name of new directory:")
list_dir.append(userinput1)
userinput2 = raw_input("Would you like to add another directory? yes/no: ")
if userinput2 == "no":
  for list in list_dir:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,list))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: for the repetition i recommend a `while` loop with a `break` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a while loop for asking directories:

## UPDATED

```
import os


root_path = r"C:\XYZ"
list_dir = []

while True:
    userinput1 = raw_input("Please enter the name of new directory:")
    list_dir.append(userinput1)
    userinput2 = None
    while userinput2 != "yes" and userinput2 != "no":
        userinput2 = raw_input("Would you like to add another directory? yes/no: ")

    if userinput2 == "no":
        break

for directory in list_dir:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, directory))
```

### Updates made

- First fix `if == "no":` to `if userinput2 == "no":`
- Second add a for to loop through the list with directory names and create one by one.

Comment: For some reason it does not give me an option to enter the name of new directory .  Also, shouldn`t          while userinput2 != "yes"   be while userinput1 != "yes"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if it's important to you that you keep a list of folders that you only create at the very end. Assuming it's not, this should solve your problem:

```
import os

root = r"C:\XYZ"

while True:
    dir_name = raw_input("Please enter the name of new directory: ")
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, dir_name))
        print("Directory '{name}' was created.".format(name=dir_name))
    except OSError:
    print("Directory '{name}' already exists.".format(name=dir_name))
    repeat = raw_input("Would you like to add another directory? yes/no: ")

    if repeat.lower() != "yes" and repeat.lower() != "y":
        break
```

If for some reason it is important to only create the list at the very end:

```
import os

root = r"."
directory_list = []

while True:
    directory_name = raw_input("Please enter the name of new directory: ")
    directory_list.append(directory_name)
    repeat = raw_input("Would you like to add another directory? yes/no: ")

    if repeat.lower() != "yes" and repeat.lower() != "y":
        break

for directory in directory_list:
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root, directory))
        print("Directory '{name}' was created.".format(name=directory))
    except OSError:
        print("Directory '{name}' already exists.".format(name=directory))
```

In both cases it will continue if the user inputs any variation of "y", "yes", "Yes", "yEs" and so on, and stops otherwise.

Hope this helps. :)